# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Preguntas\insertarHistorial.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Preguntas\insertarHistorial.php on line 9

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?, mi código esta compuesto de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php include("conexion.php"); if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){  if(isset($_GET['c']) && isset($_GET['ida'])){
    $link=Conectarse();
      $c1=$_GET['c'];
      $ida1=$_GET['ida'];
      $c = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $c1);
      $ida = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $ida1);

      
      $resultado=mysqli_query($link,"insert into historial(calificacion,fk_idUsuario) values('$c','$ida');") or die($link);
     

      if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)>0){
        print json_encode(array('estado'=>'1','mensaje'=>'Correcto'));
      }else
          print json_encode(array('estado'=>'2','mensaje'=>'Incorrecto'));
    } else
        print json_encode(array('estado'=>'3','mensaje'=>'Campos vacios')); } ?>
```

Comment: El mensaje de error se debe a esto: `die($link)`, no puedes tratar a `$link` como una cadena. Puede que además de eso la consulta esté fallando. Cambia esa parte por algo como **`die(mysqli_error($link));`** así si hay error podrás ver cuál es la causa.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas implementar `or die()` para manejar errores en tu consulta SQL, es posible hacerlo. Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que el objeto `$link` (la conexión a la base de datos) no se puede imprimir directamente con `echo` o `print`, ya que es un objeto de la clase `mysqli` o un `null`, no una cadena.

En lugar de imprimir el objeto `$link`, puedes imprimir el mensaje de error proporcionado por [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) si ocurre algún error en la consulta.

Ejemplo:

```php
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```